# Is there any way to see current query response time in browser?

Tags: php, mysql, firefox-addon

Is there any way to see current mysql query and its response time in browser?
 I am working on simple php not on any framework. Anybody know any addons for FF which gives me this information.

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I use the **profiling** function of MySQL server (from 5.0.37).

```
<?php

// profiling init
$set_profiling = $mysqli->query( 'SET profiling = 1' );

// some stuff
$result1 = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT DESTINATIONCODE, ZONENAME FROM ZONES' );
$result2 = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT ZONENAME FROM ZONES' );


// showing profiling printout
$show_profiles = $mysqli->query( 'SHOW PROFILES' );
while( $row = $show_profiles->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo '<pre>';   
    print_r( $row );    
    echo '</pre>'
}
```

In addition, if you want a more detailed report after each query you can use:

```
$show_profile = $mysqli->query( 'SHOW PROFILE' );
```

Check http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html .

That's a bit raw visualization but it works.

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [Query_ID] => 1
    [Duration] => 0.00012000
    [Query] => SELECT DESTINATIONCODE, ZONENAME FROM ZONES
)
Array
(
    [Query_ID] => 2
    [Duration] => 0.00006800
    [Query] => SELECT ZONENAME FROM ZONES
)
```

And detail for #1 query:

```
Array
(
    [Status] => (initialization)
    [Duration] => 0.000002
)
Array
(
    [Status] => checking query cache for query
    [Duration] => 0.000003
)
Array
(
    [Status] => checking privileges on cached 
    [Duration] => 0.000002
)
Array
(
    [Status] => checking permissions
    [Duration] => 0.000001
)
Array
(
    [Status] => sending cached result to clien
    [Duration] => 0.000056
)
Array
(
    [Status] => logging slow query
    [Duration] => 0.000001
)
```

Comment: Can you please change echo '</pre>' to echo '</pre>'; on line 16, or else it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox plugins do not have access to the MySQL queries that are taking place as part of your PHP code, it is simply impossible.

If you have shell access to your server, you can try looking at the MySQL Query Log : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: but in cake php we can see the current query

Comment: @user729022 in cakephp they use php for checking the execution time consider using my solution.

Comment: @user729022: CakePHP has a great bunch of code written to track and display all SQL queries that are made through the object models. Since you are not using a framework, you would need to write this code yourself similar to the way that @Ibrahim Azhar Armar suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in php by doing something like this.(the result will be in float value)

```
function time_in_float() {
    $time = microtime();
    $time = explode(" ",$time);
    $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
    return $time;
}
$startTime = time_in_float();

$query = "SELECT SOME QUERY";
mysql_query($query);

$endTime = time_in_float();

$queryTime = ($endTime - $startTime);
echo $queryTime . ' micro seconds';
```

Comment: i used ur solution but it shows 0 ,not giving exact time difference which may be 0.0006 sec

Comment: it is because we are not getting the value in float, i am updating the post on how to get the execution time in float value.

Comment: `microtime(true)` already returns float. `printf('%.7f secs', - microtime(true) + microtime(true));` outputs something like `0.0000119 secs`. Parameter `$get_as_float` was added in PHP 5.0.0, so if `microtime(true)` does not return float, I would suggest to upgrade PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox knows nothing of your mysql-queries, as they aren't handled client side. (At least, most of the time, i'm guessing you are not talking about some really esoteric situation here).

If you have a certain request (AJAX for instance, or loading a special file) that does the request, you could see the time for that ofcourse (easiest being to use the firebug plugin for that), but you can't single out queries from your PHP script.

What you can do ofcourse is time the query in PHP, and return that as a value (using `microtime()` and some basic math), but that's something else.

Comment: Do you mean they are handled *server* side?

Comment: To make it complicated, i've fixed by adding a "not" instead of "server" ;D

Answer (score 0):

add this lines to my.ini [cut paste from my WAMP]

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
# Set Slow Query Log
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = "E:/wamp/logs/slowquery.log"
#Set General Log
log = "E:/wamp/logs/genquery.log"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add new **add-ons(YSlow)** for that in Firefox. i dont know any about for other browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: Witch addon? YSlow 2.1.0 doesn't perform any server-side analysis http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/

Comment: Yes, but it knows nothing of MySQL queries, as they are handled server side. Right...?